# Microsoft Graph API - Create event subscription result in 403 response

Tags: api, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-403, subscriptions

I'm having a permission problem when trying to subscribe to calendar events for a calendar. I'm getting a 403 response.

**My setup:**

A user account with delegated permission to access a room calendar.
Full access rights through (mailbox delegation) https://outlook.office365.com/ecp

My app is using delegated permissions to the Graph API:

- Calendar.Shared.ReadWrite
- Calendars.ReadWrite

This call works:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<room-mail>/calendars
(and also appending /<calendar-id>/events)
```

But when trying to create a subscription I get a 403 response:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
(resource: users/<room-mail>/calendars/<calendar-id>/events)
```

Link to Microsoft docs for the call:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_post_subscriptions

Is this suppose to work like this at all?
Do I need more permissions?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to make this work ?

Comment: Were you able to create subscription for non primary calendar?